# File too big other options

Tags: c++, mingw, bazel, msys

If I have a `file too big` error with a `.o` file what are my options? I am using bazel 4.0 with Windows 10 and gcc 10.2.

I have already passed `-Wa,-mbig-obj`.

For more context, I previously was building using MSVC and the compilation step finished just fine with `/bigobj` but the linking stage failed because a dependency was compiled with mingw so I have to build with mingw instead.

Comment: If it's your code, you could consider to split a translation unit into multiple ones. (I once had this issue that a main application class became that big that I had to split the implementation into 3 C++ files.) In most cases, this is just a cut/paste job and not too complicated.

Comment: Ah okay I can try that. Would including too many header files in a .h be a source of bloat?

Comment: Your question about _too many header files_ is unrelated, isn't it? What I meant was to split the `.cpp` file into multiple ones. And yes, in the simplest case, you just may copy/paste the `#include`s into every new `.cpp` file which results from splittig. Too many headers may raise the compile time but I really would wonder if they increase the object size. (There might be corner-cases with static variables but I wouldn't expect this in general.) - A header is usually about declarations. That's why it might be a compiler issue but not an issue of the resulting object file.

Comment: Okay ill try to split the cpp file!